# amCharts 4: Is it possible to sort categories of stacked column chart by totals

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Is it possible to sort the categories of a category column chart with multiple stacked series by their totals?

I know that `CategoryAxis` has the property `sortBySeries` but this allows only sorting by one specific series.
Is there any equivalent for all series or a workaround like creating a not visible total series?

(Presorting data is not the best choice for me, since I would like to use `chart.invalidateRawData` later on and sorting must also done then.)

Comment: Categories are displayed in order provided to the chart. You'll need to manually sort your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current solution I ended up with is to programmatically add a `_calcTotal` attribute to each object in `chart.data`.
The value of this attribute is calculated by adding all values of all value-dataattributes.
e.g. when a single data item looks like this:

```js
{
  country: 'Germany',
  femaleVisitors: 2550,
  maleVisitors: 6029
}
```

and two stacked series for `maleVisitors` and `femaleVisitors` are created then the updated data item would look like this:

```js
{
  country: 'Germany',
  femaleVisitors: 2550,
  maleVisitors: 6029,
  _calcTotal: 8579
}
```

This calculations can be done for example when the [`beforedatavalidated`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#beforedatavalidated_event) event kicks in and every time you update the data.
Then we create a new column-series with `_calcTotal` as value-datafield and set `hidden` attribute on this series to `true`.

This series can now be used for sorting by using [`categoryAxis.sortBySeries`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/categoryaxis/#sortBySeries_property) property.

However amcharts doesn't sort the categories initially when the referenced sorting-series is hidden and **a lot** of different categories are used (> ~15).
A workaround is to call `invalidateRawData` when the chart fires the [`ready`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#ready_event) event. This leads to a dirty initial sorting animation, but hey, better than nothing.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0nr3g6es/1/